# React + Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

P.S 
Пытаюсь сделать как в [этом уроку](https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3), ничего не выходит.
Запускаю команду

```
"electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""
```

Возникает ошибка

```
[0] 'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[0] BROWSER=none yarn start exited with code 1
```

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле по запросу: [electron react boilrplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

Comment: А можно с большим количеством пояснений? Там просто много кода, я не уверен, что все из этого мне нужно

Comment: Это готовое окружение в котором вы сможете работать, всё настроено уже за вас, вам требуется только ознакомиться с расположением рабочего пространства. Темболее по запросу вы можете найти и другие шаблоны, выбрать самый оптимальный и писать код.